# How to pass an object and only change one value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data object below.

```
{
  name: "Catherine Myer",
  age: 23,
  birthday: "august"
}
```

If in need to pass the data as a prop to a component, BUT would also like to change just the age to: 24. How do i do so?

```
<NextPage data={author.age = 24}/>
```

I need the final object to be:

```
{
  name: "Catherine Myer",
  age: 24,
  birthday: "august"
}
```

Comment: Why are you directly passing `data` instead of passing three separate properties `name`, `age`, and `birthday`, which you can conveniently get from `data` by using `<NextPage {...data} />`, so you override the age as `<NextPage {...data} age={data.age + 1}/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```
<NextPage data={{...author, age: 24}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass individual prop values by spreading `author` (see [Spread Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)) and override `age` with a separate prop, eg

```jsx
const NextPage = ({ name, age, birthday }) => {
  // ...
};

<NextPage {...author} age="24" />
```

or extend the existing object and provide a new `age` property

```jsx
const NextPage = ({ data: { name, age, birthday } }) => {
  // ...
};

<NextPage data={{...author, age: 24}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [JS spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to update whichever properties you need.

```js
const author = {
  name: "Catherine Myer",
  age: 23,
  birthday: "august"
};

const data = { 
  age: 24
};

const updatedAuthor = { ...author, ...data };
```

---

Edit: I have no idea what I was thinking to make it this complicated...

<s>If you don't know which property will be overwritten, a simple `for in` loop can make the update. As a bonus, this scales up if you want to modify the value of more than one property at once.</s>

Alternatively, if you really want to (or if you make the change Mike Kamermans recommended), you can use the JS spread syntax to achieve the same.

```js
const author = {
  name: "Catherine Myer",
  age: 23,
  birthday: "august"
};

const data = { 
  age: 24
};

// OPTION 1: for in loop
let updatedAuthor = { ...author }; // optionally create a copy to avoid mutating the original object
for(let prop in data) {
  updatedAuthor[prop] = data[prop];
}

// OPTION 2: spread syntax
const propToUpdate = Object.keys(update)?.[0];
const updatedAuthor = {
  ...author,
  [propToUpdate]: update[propToUpdate]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a very complicated way of doing `{...author, ...data}`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I knew there was a way with spread syntax but somehow made it more complicated than it needs to be.